# mysql performance optimization after enabling replication

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mysql-replication, mysql5

Over the weekend I upgrade my Ubuntu server from 9.10 to 10.04 which also updated my MySQL server. I also enabled MySQL replication over to another server as slave.

I have not yet moved any application logic to use slave but I started seeing some performance issues on my master MySQL server. The app has started slowing down and the number of slow queries have increased. Any good tool which can give me more information as to what might be going on or any tips to optimize this.

Comment: Server specs? Were you writing out a binary log before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of tools, but ensure in your queries you always provide column names so replication serVices don't need to look up the columns and modify the SQL command.